# How to deploy chroma database to work with langchain

Tags: langchain, chromadb

I am trying to deploy the code from this github: https://github.com/benbaker76/FlaskGPT but am stuck on shifting over the chroma database to EC2. I know how to use docker to deploy it but am confused about what I should change the code segments in the following method`def create_vectordb():
texts = []

```
try:
    db_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'db')

    if os.path.exists(db_path):
        shutil.rmtree(db_path)
    loader_dir = DirectoryLoader('data', glob='*.json', loader_cls=JSONLoader, loader_kwargs={ 'jq_schema': '.', 'text_content': False })
    documents = loader_dir.load_and_split()
    text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=1024, chunk_overlap=200)
    texts += text_splitter.split_documents(documents)
    model_kwargs = { 'device': 'cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu' }
    encode_kwargs = { 'normalize_embeddings': True }
    embedding = HuggingFaceBgeEmbeddings(model_name='thenlper/gte-base', model_kwargs=model_kwargs, encode_kwargs=encode_kwargs)
    vectordb = Chroma.from_documents(documents=texts,
                                    embedding=embedding,
                                    persist_directory=db_path)
    logging.info(f"The '{db_path}' folder has been created.")
except Exception as e:
    logging.error(f"An error occurred while processing file: {e}")
```

`and` 
def init_llm():
global llm, qa_chain

```
try:
    db_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'db')

    model_kwargs = { 'device': 'cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu' }
    encode_kwargs = { 'normalize_embeddings': True }
    embedding = HuggingFaceBgeEmbeddings(model_name='thenlper/gte-base', model_kwargs=model_kwargs, encode_kwargs=encode_kwargs)
    vectordb = Chroma(persist_directory=db_path, embedding_function=embedding)
    retriever = vectordb.as_retriever(search_kwargs={ 'k': 10 })
    prompt_template = PromptTemplate.from_template(MY_TEMPLATE)
    chain_type_kwargs = { 'verbose': True, 'prompt': prompt_template }
    qa_chain = RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(llm=llm,
                                        chain_type='stuff',
                                        retriever=retriever,
                                        return_source_documents=False, verbose=True,
                                        chain_type_kwargs=chain_type_kwargs)
    logging.info(f"LLM initialized")
except Exception as e:
    logging.error(f"LLM failed to initialize : {e}")
```

`